# get values in JSONB by multiple keys PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have JSONB in the database and I need to get the keys and values that come in the array, the keys can change.

example JSONB -

```
{"key": "test2", "key1": "value", "key2": "value1", "key3": "value2", "key4": "value5", "name": "test"}
```

I tried to do it

```
    '@Query(value = "SELECT d.key, d.value " +
            " FROM Table table" +
            " JOIN jsonb_each_text(table.data) d ON true " +
            " WHERE table.type = ?1 AND table.time BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3"+
            " AND d.key IN ?4" , nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object>findByData(String type, Long from, Long to, String[] keys);'
```

and got,

```
    [
    [
        "key",
        "test2"
    ],
    [
        "key1",
        "value"
    ],
    [
        "name",
        "test"
    ]]
```

but I need

```
  [{
      "key":"test2",
      "key1:"value",
      "name":"test"
  }]
```

if you have any ideas please help. Maybe there are ways to change the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try tranform your list into a map that contains all key and values.

```
    // get list of object
    var listOfObjectThatSimulatefindByData = new ArrayList<>(
                    List.of(
                        new Object[]{"key1","value1"}, // any row in database
                        new Object[]{"key2","value2"}  // any row in database
                            )
                    );

    // collect all list into map
    var mapYouNeed = listOfObjectThatSimulatefindByData.stream()
                                                .collect(
                                                    Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj[0] , obj -> obj[1])
                                                    );


    // print
    System.out.println(mapYouNeed);
```

We will got this output:

```
{
key1=value1, 
key2=value2
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not manually specify either keys or values, it is required to work without explicit definitions. But thank you very much for your efforts